# How to bind last index value of an observable array in knockout js

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js

I need to show last comment to user in first page load as will as after adding new comments, new comments are successfully being added to observable array but i'm unable to show the Last comments, I'm trying this code, but it did not work.

My code is attached in JsFiddle

```js
function Comment(NoteText, CreateDate) {
    this.commentText = ko.observable(NoteText);
    this.createDate = ko.observable(CreateDate);
}

function CommentList() {
    var nm = this;
    nm.newComment = ko.observable();
    nm.allComments = ko.observableArray([{ commentText: 'Hellow world', createDate: 'some date' }]);
    nm.AddNewComment = function () {
        nm.allComments.push(new Comment(this.newComment(), Date()));
        this.newComment('');
    }
    ko.applyBindings(nm, document.getElementById("comments"));
}

    var comments = new CommentList();
    $("#allcomments").hide();
    $("#btnViewAll").click(function () {
        $("#allcomments").show();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="comments">
        <input type="text" data-bind="value:newComment" /><button data-bind="click: AddNewComment">Add New Comment</button><br />
        <hr />
        Last Comment: <strong> <span data-bind="text: allComments[allComments.length-1]"></span> </strong><button id="btnViewAll">View ALL</button>
        <br />
        <div id="allcomments">
            <h2>All Comments</h2>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Comment Text</td>
                        <td>Date</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: allComments">
                    <tr>
                        <td><span data-bind="text: commentText"></span></td>
                        <td><span data-bind="text: createDate"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Am able to add a comment by clicking on "Add New Comment" and it display in the 'All Comments' section perfectly with your code. Is there something else you are looking for?

Comment: I already mentioned that i'm able to add comment, but i'm not able to show last comment in label.

Comment: apologies... got it...

Comment: Are you not able to add another observable(like `lastComment`) to bind with the label and assign it the latest value before you clear the latest value in the `AddNewComment`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`allComments` is an observable array, so you need to use parentheses to get at the array it contains for the expression

```
"text: allComments()[allComments().length-1]"
```

For clarity, it might be nicer to make a computed named `lastComment` and use that in your binding.